# Determining pairs of arrival and departures to calculate time spent at destination

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will let me know the time spent at a particular airport based on arrival and departure times.

```
CREATE TABLE Flights
    (`ACID` varchar(6), `TIME` datetime, `STATUS` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Flights
    (`ACID`, `TIME`, `STATUS`)
VALUES
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-01 18:09:00', 'A'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-02 15:25:00', 'D'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-06 19:53:00', 'A'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-07 14:01:00', 'D'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-12 16:06:00', 'A'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-12 17:00:00', 'D'),
    ('YYYY', '2014-01-13 18:10:00', 'A'),
    ('YYYY', '2014-01-13 18:56:00', 'D'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-16 20:40:00', 'A'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-17 14:49:00', 'D'),
    ('ZZZZ', '2014-01-17 21:42:00', 'A'),
    ('ZZZZ', '2014-01-17 22:17:00', 'D'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-21 00:30:00', 'A'),
    ('XXXX', '2014-01-23 15:35:00', 'D')
;
```

The status row is either 'A' for arrival or 'D' for departure.

The output should aggregate the time spent (which is the difference between departure and arrival times) by the ACID field.

There may be cases when there is an arrival record, but no matching departure record.

I'm having a tough time "determining the pairs" so that I can do the date difference, etc..

RDBMS is MSSQL 2012

Comment: Which dbms? If you can use analytic functions `LAG` may be what you want.

Comment: in this case it's MSSQL 2012

Comment: Can't add this as an answer because it is incomplete, but maybe it can help you in some way:
select b.time as departure, a.time as arrival, (b.time-a.time) as timespent 
 from Flights a
 join Flights b 
 on a.acid = b.acid
 where a.status = 'A' and b.status = 'D'
It's not dealing with those ACID repeated records yet.

Comment: @FilipeYaBaPolido That doesn't really work...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab76d/1

Comment: Works here, but it is incomplete, I know. I was trying to point a direction, not a full resolution, if so I would post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48c90/17 :

```
SELECT ACID, DATEDIFF(HH, TIME ,
(SELECT TOP 1 b.TIME FROM Flights b WHERE b.STATUS = 'D' AND b.TIME > a.TIME))
FROM  Flights a
WHERE STATUS = 'A'
```

It gives you this result :

```
| ACID | COLUMN_1 |
|------|----------|
| XXXX |       21 |
| XXXX |       19 |
| XXXX |        1 |
| YYYY |        0 |
| XXXX |       18 |
| ZZZZ |        1 |
| XXXX |       63 |
```

You can change the `DATEDIFF(HH` to `DATEDIFF(DD` to have diff in days.

Take a look [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2508/sql-server-datediff-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will help you with this - I have only included the `datetime` column; you can add other columns to it if you need:

```
SELECT A.ArrivalTime, D.DepartureTime 
FROM (SELECT TIME AS ArrivalTime, ACID
      FROM  Flights
      WHERE STATUS = 'A') A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TIME AS DepartureTime, ACID
           FROM FLIGHTS
           WHERE STATUS = 'D') D
WHERE   A.ArrivalTime < D.DepartureTime
AND     A.ACID = D.ACID
```

And you can use the `DATEDIFF` function to calculate the difference.

Comment: Interesting.. I end up with 28 returned rows (exactly double). Shouldn't I expect the same (14)?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48c90/4